# ListView setting background color

Tags: android, background-color

I have this code in my ArrayAdapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getItem(position).getString("text") + " = " + getItem(position).getString("my"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    if(getItem(position).getString("my") == "0") {
        row.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.ekvi));
    }
    TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    tv.setText(getItem(position).getString("text"));
    tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);

    return row;
}
```

Though background color isn't applied. I checked "my" string and it is really sometimes "0", so it must work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you have try using `if(getItem(position).getString("my")equals("0")` ?

Comment: try to use equalsIgnoreCase().

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase doesn't make any difference when comparing a string that contains a number :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.equals() to compare Strings objects.`

- `== compares Strings Refrences(memory location)`
- `.equals() compares Strings characters(value)`

**Like**

```
if(getItem(position).getString("my").equals("0")) {
```

Comment: Thanks! I really forgot that (was programming C# much where == works too).